# What does "the gigantic gates and lines of soldiers that protected the castle that was the Soviet embassy" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, swimming-in-the-dark, tomasz-jedrowski

I would like to know what "the
gigantic gates and lines of soldiers that protected the
castle that was the Soviet embassy" means in the following sentences:

> We whizzed off, speeding seamlessly and effortlessly along Ujazdowskie
> Avenue. We passed the run-down palaces of the long-forgotten
> aristocracy, the Łazienki Gardens with my hidden deer, and **the
> gigantic gates and lines of soldiers that protected the castle that
> was the Soviet embassy**. After that the city turned sparse. We passed
> endless stretches of identical blocks, *blokowisko* upon *blokowisko*
> with mud fields in-between, where riotous hordes of children played.
> We passed factories, smoking behemoths, big and solemn like sooty
> churches. The radio was on, playing something by the Velvet
> Underground. Nico sang in her low, litanic voice, bells ringing and a
> guitar jittering, like a flickering mirage.

- [Tomasz Jedrowski, *Swimming in the Dark*, Chapter 6](https://www.booker6.com/book/202006/842_51.html)

In this novel which is set in the 1980's in Poland under the socialist regime, where homosexuality was socially unacceptable, the protagonist Ludwik (a university graduate) left Poland in 1981 to live in the United States of America. And he remembers what it was like back then in Poland, where he decided to spend some days at the country house of Hania's family with his lover Janusz, Hania's brother Maksio, and Maksio's girlfriend Agata. So they (the five of them) drove towards the country house in the car.

In this part, I wonder it would be right to understand that what protected the castle that had once been the Soviet embassy were the gigantic gates *and* the lines of soldiers, or that only the lines of soldiers protected the castle.

I am an English learner from South Korea, so thank you for your patience in advance as I may not know obvious things. I would very much appreciate your help. :)

Comment: I am confused by the phrase "my hidden deer". Does the narrator actually own the deer in the park? Is deer singular or plural? And why are they/ it hidden?

Comment: Please consider asking question like this one on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com) rather than here. If your question is about what a character is thinking, or what the character's words might mean for the sake of the story, that does belong here. But a question like this one, which involves simply *How do I parse this sentence?*, is really an ELL question, not a Lit SE one.

Comment: My prior comment is to the OP, not to Pete.

Comment: When In struggling with something relating to a real location, I find it can be helpful see if I can find it on Street View. This seems the likely location https://goo.gl/maps/7FHhAeVfRp3ViDB27

Comment: Dear @Pete, I think "my hidden deer" would be related to the fact that the narrator once visited the Łazienki Gardens when he was young with his mother and grandmother, and saw a worker piling bundles of straw for the deer. The narrator was very surprised that there were deer hidden from everyone's sight, and envied them as they seemed to lead a life which is protected yet free.

Comment: Dear verbose, thank you very much for the comment. I thought it would be okay to ask questions here as it had to do with a novel, but I think I was wrong... Probably I will try that site you recommended. Thank you.

Comment: @PastaAddict Your questions are on-topic here - please don't get scared away from this site completely :-) [Community discussion revealed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1127/17) that even relatively basic `meaning` questions are OK for this site. But, if you can distinguish between the queries that are **purely linguistic** (e.g. just the meaning of a word or phrase) and those that are **more contextual** (e.g. dependent on understanding the setting or characters of the story), then the relevant experts would be found on ELL for the first type and Lit for the second type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both the *gates* and the *lines of soldiers* are security measures, they both protect the Soviet embassy. The syntax of the sentence shows that too. If it were only the soldiers that protected the embassy, "the gigantic gates" would not fit into the sentence. The gigantic gates of what? The sentence would need to be rewritten as follows:

> We passed the run-down palaces of the long-forgotten aristocracy, the Łazienki Gardens with my hidden deer, the gigantic gates of the castle that was the Soviet embassy, and the lines of soldiers that protected it.